# SQL server Log Shipping

Tags: sql-server, clustering, failover, log-shipping, disaster-recovery

I have two node SQL server standard failover cluster.

I need to setup single node DR using log Shipping method.

Want to ask after switch over to DR how we can setup, plan so that application can connect automatically to DR database server without any changes on application connection string.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Without changes to application means you would have to do it at "the network layer". With that I mean things like DNS, rename machine etc.

If you can modify the connection string, then you can *try* below connection attribute. It is really meant for database mirroring, so you would have to try if it makes work in other situations:

```
Failover Partner=myMirrorServerAddress;
```

And, of course, make sure you handle all the other things that you have to handle when you move a database from one instance to another, like scheduled jobs, logins, linked servers etc. I.e., everything that is stored outside the database and is required for the system/application to be functioning.

Comment: Database mirroring is not feasible I need to use Log Shipping only. Do you have DNS changes steps
Thanks

Comment: DNS is at the OS/Network layer, and should be handled by the personell at your site who does these kind of things. Invite them to a discussion regarding the feasibility to use DNS changes to "redirect" a client app. You might also use a client alias to re-direct, which is something done on the *client computer. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/create-or-delete-a-server-alias-for-use-by-a-client